# Sharing url on google plus via google plus button

Tags: google-plus-one

I want to share my url on google plus using the google plus share button.

The url successfully shared on my google plus but it displays an error when I click on the post button.

```
"An error occurred. Please try again."
```

Here is my code

```
<a href="https://m.google.com/app/plus/x/?v=compose&content={$var_topic.directlink2}">Plus</a>
```

When the url successfully posted then why it also display the error?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the Google+ share button instead.
https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/share/